# Leaking tub nipple

Tags: plumbing

I had 2 leaks in my tub: one from the faucet area, one at the tub spout.  I fixed the faucet leak  by replacing the cartridge.  But the spout still leaks.  It's NOT the spout.  It's the pipe coming out of the wall.  With the spout removed, there is still a drip coming out of the pipe.  (Is the pipe called a nipple?)

Can I just tighten the pipe by turning it clockwise with (say) vice grips?
Do I need to replace that pipe somehow?  Or perhaps an o-ring hiding in there somewhere?

Thanks!

Comment: is the leak coming out of the spout pipe or from around the spout pipe?  No you do NOT want to give a twist with vice grips!  Is the spout even threaded at all??  Did the spout fitting thread into a threaded pipe coming out of the wall or was it a push on with a set screw?

Comment: The leak is coming right out of the spout pipe,  Both the spout and the pipe coming out of the wall are threaded: the spout threads onto the pipe easily (used Teflon tape).  I was concerned about just twisting the pipe....afraid I'd end up with water everywhere!

Comment: That sounds like the valve feeding the spout is leaking.  Is it a single handle or double handles, if it's single can you remove it, and remove the escutcheon plate and take a picture?  Is there a makers mark on the handles or the plate?   The problem with messing with the nipple is when you thread back on the spout it won't be tight unless it's upside down or some such.

Comment: All the parts are Mixet, according to Home Depot and what I've put on. It's one handle, with a hot/cold lever and a on/off knob.  I've removed the escutcheon plate, the handles, and the cartridge and replaced all.  That's what fixed the leak coming from the faucet.

Comment: Not sure where the valve feeding the spout is, but a leading valve seem reasonable based on what I'm seeing.

Comment: Adding a picture of the leaking area, preferably with the tub spout itself (but none of the piping behind it) removed (if possible), would definitely help